# glossary line indent of second line is not the same than in the first one

Tags: glossaries

I have a problem with the formatting of the glossary. If the text is too long for one line, it continues in the next one. But the problem is that the line indent isn't the same than in the first line. where can i change this? attached you will find my demo code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Inputencoding: Umlaute richtig eingeben
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %Fontencoding: Worte mit Umlauten richtig trennen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[
nonumberlist, %keine Seitenzahlen anzeigen
nogroupskip,  %kein Abstand
acronym,      %ein Abkürzungsverzeichnis erstellen
toc,          %Einträge im Inhaltsverzeichnis
section]      %im Inhaltsverzeichnis auf section-Ebene erscheinen
{glossaries}

%Ein eigenes Symbolverzeichnis erstellen
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newglossary[slg]{acronyms}{syi}{syg}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}

%Den Punkt am Ende jeder Beschreibung deaktivieren
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

%Glossar-Befehle anschalten
\makeglossaries

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Settings%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setlength{\glslistdottedwidth}{.25\hsize} %Punktlänge einstellen

\newglossaryentry{romanletter}{name={\textbf{\large Lateinische Symbole}},description={}}

\newglossaryentry{greekletter}{name={\textbf{\large Griechische Symbole}},description={}}


\newglossaryentry{symb:omega}{
name=$\Omega$,
description={Gierbeschleunigung},
parent=greekletter,
sort=symbolomega, 
type=symbolslist
}
\newglossaryentry{symb:M0}{
name=$M_{\mathrm{0}}$,
description={gemessenes Biegemoment mittels Vollmessbrücken DMS Schaltung},
parent=romanletter,
sort=symbolM0, 
type=symbolslist
}


\newacronym{AVL-DRIVE}{AVL-DRIVE}{objektive Fahrbarkeitsanalysesoftware von AVL List GmbH}
\newacronym{NCTE}{NCTE}{Deutsche Firma, die sich auf berührungslose Drehmomentmessung spezialisiert hat}


\glsaddall[types=symbolslist]
\glsaddall[types=\acronymtype]


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=symbolslist, style=sublistdotted]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis, style=listdotted]
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

ADDED screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an screenshot of the result you got?

Comment: i have added a screenshot :)

Comment: The `acronym` package option creates the list of acronyms. The line `\newglossary[slg]{acronyms}{syi}{syg}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}` isn't needed and conflicts with `\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}`, which has the same file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I have now made my own glossary style:

```
 \newglossarystyle{altlistdotted}%
    {%
       \glossarystyle{tree}%
       \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
         \hangindent0pt\relax
         \parindent0pt\relax
         \makebox[\glslistdottedwidth][l]%
         {%
           \glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{##2}}%
           \unskip\leaders\hbox to 2.9mm{\hss.}\hfill\strut
         }%
         \parbox[t]{\linewidth-\glslistdottedwidth}{##3}\par}%
    }
    \glossarystyle{altlistdotted}
```

The result was, that the acronymlist is ok, but the symbollist isn't like i want it (see screenshot:[image: This is the acronymlist]

The symbollist looks like it would has the style=tree... but why?[image: symbollist]

Comment: I think this should be moved to your question since it isn't actually an answer. You're using some deprecated commands (`\glossarystyle` and `\glossaryentryfield`) so it would also help to say what version of `glossaries` you have installed.